# How can I print the highest value from a Spark RDD in java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm doing an excercice where I'm required to do some "filtering" based on a file that has more than 13 millions of lines, here's a sample:

```
18;03;2015;082XX S MOZART ST;THEFT;$500 AND UNDER;STREET;41.743803922;-87.693687357
19;03;2015;052XX S CORNELL AVE;ROBBERY;ARMED: HANDGUN;RESIDENCE PORCH/HALLWAY;41.80061868;-87.585887262
19;03;2015;020XX N PULASKI RD;CRIMINAL DAMAGE;TO VEHICLE;STREET;41.918320523;-87.726596048
18;03;2015;001XX W RANDOLPH ST;ASSAULT;SIMPLE;RESIDENCE;41.884472382;-87.633378182
```

The questions I have to awnser are:

-Day of the year with the highest crime rate?
-Month with the highest average crime rate?
-Month by year with the highest crime rate?

I would like to know how to print/filter the highest and the avarege... I'll insert my code here (where I've awnsered the other questions I had):

```
Public class Main {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    System.out.println("Start");
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Pratic Spark");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> arquivo = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost/Frameworks/spark/ocorrencias_criminais.csv");
  
    /* --- EXERCÍCIO 1 ---- Filters colun nº 2 from dataset - YEAR ----*/ 
    JavaRDD<String> YearRDD  = arquivo.map(s -> 
    {String[] fields= s.split(";") ; 
    return fields[2];
    });
    // print results
    System.out.println("Answer to question 1 -> " + YearRDD.countByValue());
    
    /* ---- EXERCÍCIO 2 ---- Filters "Narcotics" type from colun nº 4 ----*/
    JavaRDD<String> JustNarcotics = arquivo.filter(s -> {
        String [] fields = s.split(";");
        String type = campos [4];
        return type.equalsIgnoreCase("NARCOTICS");
    });
    /* ---- EXERCÍCIO 2 ---- Filter by year ---- EXERCÍCIO 2 ---- */ 
    JavaRDD<String> YearByNarcoticsRDD = JustNarcotics.map(s -> {
        String [] fields = s.split(";");
        return fields[2];
        
    });
    //Prints the result ---- EXERCÍCIO 2 ----         
    System.out.println("Answer to the question 2 -> " + AnoporNarcoticsRDD.countByValue());
    
// ---- EXERCÍCIO 3 ---- Aplying filter for even days ---- 
        JavaRDD<String> EvenDayRDD = arquivo.filter(s -> {
        String [] fields= s.split(";");   
        String type = fields[4];
        int day = Integer.valueOf(fields[0]);
        return(type.equalsIgnoreCase("NARCOTICS")&&(day % 2 == 0));
        });
   
    JavaRDD<String> EvenDaysRDD = EvenDayMapRDD.map(s -> {
         String [] fields= s.split(";");
        return fields[0];
    });
    //prints the result ---- EXERCÍCIO 3 ----         
    System.out.println("Awswer to the question 3 -> " + EvenDayMapRDD.countByValue());
```

Thanks!

PS: some things may be wrong in the code above, it was in Portuguese but I translated it so it could be better understood. It is working fine.

PS2: I haven't done anything yet for the questions I mentioned (for highest and average). It's the first time I have to program in java and Spark so I could use some help, even with this "basics" things.

Answer (score 0):

As answered here, [How to filter in Spark using two "conditions"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64979082/how-to-filter-in-spark-using-two-conditions/64993929#64993929)

Convert your data rdd to dataframe. Once you have the data frame, everything will get simpler.

```
Dataset<Row> summary = crimeInfoDataset.groupBy("year", "month", "day", "crimeType").count().toDf("year", "month", "day", "crimeType", "count");
```

To find max crime rate by month.

```
summary.groupBy("month").max("count").show(false);
```

To find max crime rate by day.

```
summary.groupBy("day").max("count").show(false);
```

To find max crime rate by crimetype.

```
summary.groupBy("crimeType").max("count").show(false);
```

To find max crime rate by month and year.

```
summary.groupBy("month", "year").max("count").show(false);
```

Replace max by avg, min and likes as per your requirements.

Comment: Hi, I tried that, maybe I did something wrong because it did not worked. The error presented is "Search Dependency at Maven repositories for Crimes" and an error for me to "creat a javaSparkContext method". `code` List<String> crimes = new ArrayList<>(); 
        crimes.add("/home2/ead2020/SEM2/jessica.emanuele/ocorrencias_criminais.csv");

      JavaRDD<String> crimesRdd = javaSparkContext().parallelize(crimes);

Comment: The javaSparkContext is the same as the one you created.